# I'm using nightwatch framework for testing,i get this range error .On encountering the error execution just stops without any report

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, automation, nightwatch.js

I've tried updating chromedriver and installing latest node package but still i keep getting this at times.Thanks in advance.Error details are below :
 `RangeError: Invalid string length at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9) at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) ✖ failed RangeError: Invalid string length at ChromeDriver.onStderr (/Users/h895680/Downloads/AutomationCode/Off5th Desktop/Sfcc-TestAutomation-Off5th/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/wd-instances/base-wd-server.js:333:25) at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9) at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)`

Below is the code where we are trying to get specific element location to scroll to

```
    function scrollToTheElement(webElement) {
    client.pause(2000);
                client.getLocation(webElement, function (result) {
                    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
                    console.log("***************element location stringify:- " + jsonString);
                    var yCoOrdinate = jsonString.substring(jsonString.lastIndexOf(':'), jsonString.length).replace(':', '').replace(/}/g, '').trim();
    
                    var expectedYcoOrdinate = Number(yCoOrdinate) - 200;
                    client.execute('window.scrollTo(0,' + expectedYcoOrdinate + ')');
    
                })
            };
```

Comment: Please post your test code.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably been thought of but it looks like its beginning and ending the quotes too early and then starting them again -

```
client.execute('window.scrollTo(0,' + expectedYcoOrdinate + ')');
```

Try -

```
client.execute('window.scrollTo(0, + expectedYcoOrdinate + )');
```

or -

```
client.execute('window.scrollTo(0, {expectedYcoOrdinate})');
```